# C++にてvector subscript out of rangeというエラーの解決方法が分からない

Tags: c++

[AtCoderの問題](https://atcoder.jp/contests/abc157/tasks/abc157_b)にて以下のコードを書きました。入力を与えて実行するとvector subscript out of rangeというエラーメッセージが表示されプログラムが実行されません。定義している配列の範囲がおかしいために生じていると考えたのですが、[回答例(pdf2ページ目)](https://img.atcoder.jp/abc157/editorial.pdf)も同じようにしており、なぜエラーになるのかが分かりません。原因、改善点を教えて頂けると幸いです。

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<vector<int>>a(3, vector<int>(3));
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            cin >> a[i][j];
        }
    }
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int>b(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> b[i];
    }

    vector<vector<bool>>flag(3, vector<bool>(3, false));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                if (a[i][j] == b[k]) flag[i][j] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (flag[i][0] && flag[i][1] && flag[i][2]) cout << "Yes" << endl;
        else if (flag[0][i] && flag[1][i] && flag[2][i])cout << "Yes" << endl;
        else if (flag[0][0] && flag[1][1] && flag[2][2])cout << "Yes" << endl;
        else if (flag[0][2] && flag[1][1] && flag[2][0])cout << "Yes" << endl;
        else cout << "No" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: 実行環境（OS,コンパイラ）は何ですか？C++Builderで実行してみましたが、エラーは出ませんでした。

Comment: OSはwindows10でコンパイラはvisual　studiocode　2017を使っています。

Comment: 「入力例1」では `n = 7` になりますので、`if (a[i][j] == b[k]) ...` の部分で "vector subscript out of range" が発生することになります。

Comment: 解答例も同じように配列を用意してるように思うのですが解答例と僕のコードとで何が違うんですかね....

Comment: 解答例も壊れていますが、境界チェックが行われないC配列という点が異なりますね…。

Comment: なるほど、配列の用意の仕方が違うんですね。みなさんありがとうございます。

Comment: for文を書き換えることで解決することができました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::vector::operator[]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/standard-library/vector-class?view=vs-2019#op_at)のドキュメントに

> _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL を 1 または 2 に定義してコンパイルすると、ベクターの境界外の要素にアクセスしようとした場合に実行時エラーが発生します。

と説明されています。また[`_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/standard-library/iterator-debug-level?view=vs-2019)の説明にはデバッグビルドの際、`_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL`の既定値は`2`であると書かれています。
そのため、デバッグビルドを行うと`std::vector`はアクセス毎に境界チェックを行います。

また、`operator[]`とは別に常に境界チェックを行う`at()`関数も用意されています。

C言語の配列にはもちろん境界チェック機能はありません。この点が解答例との違いとなります。

Comment: ご丁寧な回答ありがとうございます。完全に納得することができました。ありがとうございます。